# Rails coffee script throws error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I use rails 3.1.0rc4 and coffee-script 2.2.0.
app/assets/javascripts/application.js includes:

```
//= require users
```

In app/assets/javascripts/users.js I have following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert('OK');
});
```

How to convert it to coffee-script? When I replace:

```
jQuery(document).ready
```

with

```
$->
```

and change the filename from users.js to users.js.coffee

it throws ExecJS::RuntimeError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your problem is simple: The input

```
$->
```

causes the CoffeeScript compiler to complain

```
Error: Parse error on line 1: Unexpected '->'
```

You need to either add a space:

```
$ -> alert 'OK'
```

or use explicit parentheses:

```
$(-> alert 'OK')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready ($) ->
  alert('OK')
```

Comment: I still get ExecJS::RuntimeError